# Exchanging words with regex in multiple lines

Tags: regex

I am using RegexBuddy software to change this:

```
Adam Sandler
```

Into this:

```
Sandler, Adam
```

Having very little knowledge about regex, I searched and found the command to solve this

```
([^_]+) (.+)
```

and to replace: `$2, $1`

It works. But there is a problem with multiple line. How can I make it work when the input is like this?

```
Adam Sandler
Rob Schneider
Ben Stiller
```

Now, output is like this:

```
Stiller, Adam Sandler
Rob Schneider
Ben
```

Comment: You just need the equivalent of the `m` modifier and `^$` in your regex. _Really_ glad to see that you tried it yourself before asking. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following settings:

- ^$ Match at line breaks
- Line by line

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A perl equivalent,

```
sub revName{
    my $fullname = "@_";
    my ($lastname, $firstname);
    if($fullname =~ /(\w+)\s+(\w+)/){
        $firstname = $1; 
        $lastname =  $2;
     }
    my $revname = "$lastname, $firstname";
    return $revname;
}
```